# The ":active" css tag do not work? (I use Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a website as an excercise. I am using Bootstrap to have some help.
The thing is that I write an own style.css, and added an ":active" (and NOT WORK)

Here is my css:
    body{
        background-color: whitesmoke;
    }

```
.thumb_btn{
    background-color: #FC93C1;
    border-color: #fd439e;
    color: #555555;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
}

.thumb_btn:hover{
    background-color: #fd439e;
    border-color: #fd439e;
    color: #2f2f2f;
}

**.thumb_btn:active{
    background-color: #5b0a13;
    border-color: #5b0a13;
    color: #dadada;
}**
```

Here is the HTML:

```
    <meta name="description" content="Make-up blog">
    <meta name="author" content="Rodrigo Ramos">

    <title>Dreams & Feels</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="img/icon.PNG">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css/">
</head>

...

    <!-- Thumbnails -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="img/making_up.jpg" alt="making_up" class="img-circle">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3 class="text-center">Making Up</h3>
                        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
  --->                      <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary center-block thumb_btn" role="button"><strong>Introduce in the world!</strong></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="img/maquillaje_theme.jpg" alt="themes" class="img-circle">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3 class="text-center">Themes & Moments</h3>
                        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
 --->                       <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary center-block thumb_btn" role="button"><strong>Introduce in the world!</strong></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="img/warehouse.jpg" alt="warehouse" class="img-circle">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h3 class="text-center">Make-Up Warehouse</h3>
                        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
--->                        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary center-block thumb_btn" role="button"><strong>Introduce in the world!</strong></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END Thumbnails -->
```

As you can see, I have added my own css after the bootstrap ones.

I DO NOT KNOW WHY!!!!!

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Learn about specificity in CSS. Your selector has lower specificity than Bootstrap's selector.

Comment: Great, it is solved! ;)